# java queue not deallocating

Tags: java, memory-management, methods, queue

I call the method below and each time 'finishedRacers' has the same objects in it. I tried putting a .clear(), and using **new** to allocate new memory for it but every time I re-enter the method it has the same objects back in it. Any ideas as to why finishedRacers keeps holding the objects even after I try to re-allocate it and clear it?

```
@Override
public Queue<Racer> stopThenResetEvent(){
    Queue<Racer> q = new LinkedList<Racer>();
    while(!finishedRacers.isEmpty()) q.add(finishedRacers.poll());
    return q;
}
```

Not sure if it would matter, but the class has inheritance involved and the finishedRacers queue is declared in the abstract class that this extends. The abstract class inherits from an interface.

edit:

finishedRacers is declared the same way as q, its a Queue implemented with LinkedList. The queue is declared in the abstract class that this class extends. It goes IEvent (Interface) --> Event (Abstract, where queue is declared) --> GroupEvent (the class where this overridden method is being called). I call this method with the intentions of clearing the finishedRacers queue and returning the objects held in it.

When I call this multiple times, without changing the state of the event (adding new racers, starting a race, etc), but just call this method again it will continually return the same queue of racers. But my expectation is that once it is called, unless more racers are added to the finishedRacers queue, it should an empty queue.

Comment: Exactly what type is `finishedRacers`? Can you please post a more complete example, so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: This code is not related to mentioned problem, try to find out troubles in another place. Add more code where finishedRecords involved.

Comment: You might consider changing `Queue#poll()` to [remove()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#remove%28%29) so you would get an Exception (instead of a null) if the Queue is empty. You also may need to `synchronize (finishedRacers)`; what makes you think this is where your bug is?

Comment: What's the purpose of this method? It would be semantically identical to just `return finishedRacers;`, or to use `finishedRacers` or its accessor method instead of calling this method at all.

Comment: aleks: the only context this code is used in is when i directly call it with the intent of adding the finishedRacers to a queue in another class and printing out the results. i debugged the code, and while stepping the only anomaly is that the queue keeps the objects in it, but poll() i thought was supposed to remove them and i also tried clear() and allocating a new queue but the queue always has the finished racers in it again. there are no lines of code being run in-between me calling this function multiple times

Comment: elliot: i check if the queue is empty before polling ejp: i need to empty this array to prepare for a new array of results and I'm saving them in another array in another class, thats why i copy it and return that

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to find a bug in so small pice of code.

Use next code snippet for **finishedRacers**. Extend list below with a methods you use in your code and instanciate **finishedRacers** with **BugFinderList**

It will helps you to find a bug.

---

```
public class BugFinderList extends LinkedList {

    @Override
    public synchronized boolean add(Object o) {
        boolean result = super.add(o);
        System.out.println("[Add] List size is ["+size()+"]");
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void clear() {
        super.clear();
        System.out.println("[Clear] List size is ["+size()+"]");
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized Object poll() {
        Object result = super.poll();
        System.out.println("[Poll] List size is ["+size()+"]");
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: finishedRacers isn't a class, its a Queue<Racer>... racers just a class that holds information, nothing special. I dont implement my own queue class or anything

Comment: Replace finishedRacers declaration with BugFinderList end check logs.  **finishedRacers = new BugFinderList();**

Comment: The output from BugFinderList only gets outputted the FIRST time the method runs. Any ideas? edit: when i debug and step it goes into the LinkedList.class (superclass) instead of the BugFinderList code when calling my method more than once. The first time it goes into the BugFinderList.

Comment: Edit: i wasn't using the BugFinderList when doing the new on finishedRacers, now that I have it continues to print out the same thing every time I run the method. It says that I have zero elements before I leave and when I re-enter its back up to 3.

Comment: Words are not so "rich" as code is. Please, provide finished code sample which cause troubles. It will definitely accelerate problem resolution.

Comment: when simplifying my code for the sake of the example, it works properly. The actual code is quite long, I'll see if I can make a small example that re-produces the problem but if i can't should I post a link to a google doc for it?

Comment: It would be nice to have a look to the real code, issue seems inresting

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the code that printed out the racers. This was the problem code:

```
q = currentEvent.getCurrentFinished();
if(q.isEmpty()) q.addAll(finishedRacers.get(run));
```

I did not know until doing research that calling the addAll method on the return would add it to the referenced queue also, I thought the change would be local. Using this code fixed it:

```
Queue<Racer> q1 = currentEvent.getCurrentFinished();
if(q1.isEmpty()) q.addAll(finishedRacers.get(run));
else q.addAll(q1);
```

This way I never call addAll on the returned queue.